# How to use nodejs to call the bat file that needs to enter parameters and skip the pause

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to call the bat file with nodejs

I do the following:

in test.bat

```sh
set /p a=please input a:
pause
set /p b=please input b:
echo %a%  %b%
```

in node i installed [execa](https://github.com/sindresorhus/execa#readme) and the code like this:

```
const execa = require('execa');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const testPath = path.join(__dirname, './test');

const subprocess = execa(path.join(testPath, "test.bat"), [], {
    cwd: testPath
});

subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`output:${data}`)
    if (/a/ig.test(data)) {
        subprocess.stdin.write('1');
        //stop in here
        //subprocess.stdin.end()
    } else if ((/b/ig.test(data))) {
        subprocess.stdin.write('jpg');
        //subprocess.stdin.end()
    }
});

subprocess.stdout.on('end', (data) => {
    console.log(`end${data}`)
});
subprocess.stdout.on('close', (data) => {
    console.log(`close${data}`)
});
subprocess.stdout.on('error', (data) => {
    console.log(`error${data}`)
});
```

When met `pause`, it will stop. What should i do to skip `pause`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply send new line '\n' char 'a' was almost everywhere - fixed a bit your regulars too.
In case you are happy with mind pressing accept under voting button.

```
const execa = require('execa');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const testPath = path.join(__dirname, './test');

const subprocess = execa(path.join(testPath, "test.bat"), [], {
    cwd: testPath
});

subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`output:${data}`)
    if (/a:/ig.test(data)) {
        subprocess.stdin.write('1');
    } else if ((/b:/ig.test(data))) {
        subprocess.stdin.write('jpg');
    } else if(data.indexOf("any key") > 0)
        subprocess.stdin.write('\n');
});

subprocess.stdout.on('end', (data) => {
    console.log(`end ${data}`)
});
subprocess.stdout.on('close', (data) => {
    console.log(`close ${data}`)
});
subprocess.stdout.on('error', (data) => {
    console.log(`error ${data}`)
});
```

Output:

```
output:please input a:
output:Press any key to continue . . .
output:
output:please input b:
output:1  jpg
end undefined
close false
```